# Через dolist найти сумму отрицательных чисел возведенную в квадрат

Tags: lisp

Как через dolist найти сумму отрицательных чисел возведенную в квадрат?

Нашел сумму

```
(defun sum (lat)
       (cond ((null lat) 0)
         ((listp (car lat)) (+ (sum (car lat))
                       (sum (cdr lat))))
         (t (+ (car lat)
               (sum  (cdr lat))))))
```

А  как это сделать через dolist?

Comment: а точно нужна сумма возведенная в квадрат, а не сумма квадратов?

Comment: Приведённая Вами функция точно работает правильно? Я добавил её, потом запустил (sum `(1 2 3 -4 5 -7)), по идее я должен был увидеть в результате 121, а вижу 0.

Comment: @RomanPodymov, в функции нет проверки на знак числа, поэтому для твоего списка сумма - 0, и квадрат суммы, соответственно, то же 0

Comment: @Grundy Получается, что даже версия без dolist нерабочая?

Comment: @RomanPodymov, Да, на самом деле она просто считает сумму всех элементов, включая элементов вложенных списков